# Upgrades/Repairs Mongoose XR-150

Tags: maintenance, mountain-bike, chain, upgrades

First time posting here for bikes. I have an old wally world free xr-150. It was my favorite bike as a kid when it was all about fun. It's been sitting around for many years. No real rust or tarnish. I know its not a posh riding bike, however I like it and don't feel like buying a new one. That being said it needs a new chain as far as I can tell, as one of the links are rusted. I won't know much else until I got out and take it for a spin. Without a manual I'm going with experience and dumb luck figuring out what it needs. Anyone have any info as to anything specific I need chain wise? Was just going to buy a multi-speed chain of the correct length for a replacement.

Also, any immediate things I should upgrade? Like I said as a kid it never presented me with any issues, broken parts, etc. Maybe one of the few non-lemons out there. Just looking forward to keeping it in shape and many more years of use. I know there are a lot of new parts out there and just trying to wrap my head around what I should upgrade it with and why.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SE. Would you consider editing to clarify what your specific question is exactly? Are you asking about what chain you should buy? Remember to make sure that your question is answerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First off, check the brakes, if they are working, take it for a ride and make a list of things you notice.  Even with a rusted link it might still work.  I have a 20 yr old Huffy MTB with the original chain and it still works (although it has other issues).

When getting a new chain, you should get a new freewheel (I'm assuming) as well.  They are easy DIY, pop the back wheel off and take into your local shop and tell them "I need a chain, a new one of these, and the tool to remove it".  I did that same thing for my current bike and it took longer to ring me out.  When re-installing the freewheel, I advise putting some grease on it.  they are self tightening and hopefully the grease will make it easier to come off later.

Other things to consider:

1. Tires
2. Tubes
3. Wheel truing (our smaller selves loved to inflict pain on bike wheels)
4. Brake shoes

Check with the local shop about getting their opinion and a tune up.